# How to check out a project from a server with Git

Tags: eclipse, git, svn, path, tortoisegit

You may classify my question to the layman's level, but I am using Git for the first time (til now I used TortoiseSVN) and I am not sure how I can check out an existing project from a server, so as to have it available on my local machine in a folder. I have installed Git Bash. Should I run it (Gui), select *New Archiv* and then specify the path of the project in the server? Is there a better Git framework to install, which is appropriate to make the same task more easily?

I would appreciate also some screenshots if needed in the answers.

**Update:** I have installed also TortoiseGit. I want to create a new clone by a right click in a directory, but the new Clone is not available after the right click. Does it need additional configuration? If no, what should I do from TortoiseGit to checkout an existing project?

Comment: have you tried googling it: http://www.vogella.com/articles/EGit/article.html#clone_respository ?

Comment: @AdamAdamaszek: Yes you are right. I have already seen it, but I have finally to checkout the project with "Git over SVN". I think it cannot be done in Eclipse, therefor I have installed TortoiseSVN. But I still cannot create a Git Clone as I state in my Upadate.

Comment: If you have installed TortoiseGit correctly, then `Git Clone...` should be visible in you right click menu. http://www.wildkatz.org/git-windows-part-2-cloning/

Comment: Are you trying to check it out / clone from git, or SVN?

Comment: @Eloff: Surprisingly though it does not appear. The right click produces the same output as on https://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/ . No clone

Comment: @AdamAdamaszek: I have only Git so far installed. From Git.

Comment: @arjacsoh: ok, it seems you already have an empty git repository. You probably created it by mistake. Look for a hidden directory `.git` in the directory and any parent directory. You could also try right-clicking in any other folder...

Comment: @Eloff: You are right. An empty git repository was already created. I discovered the hidden .git file you supposed to have been created. Modify your answer, including that statement, so as me to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd usually recommend learning git from command line. But if you are already familiar with TortoiseSVN then [TortoiseGIT](https://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/) is a good tool for you.

Also, I think you should learn git very well. I can recommend the book [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book).

To "check out" a git repository is called **clone** in the git world (you will get a whole copy of the server repository). This can be done either from command line or TortoiseGIT.

git bash:

```
$ cd /path/to/my/projects
$ git clone url-to-server-repo
```

**Update:**
Since you get the "normal" TortoiseGit menu (without clone option), it seems you already have a local git repository. You probably created an empty git repository by mistake. Look for a hidden directory `.git` in the project directory or any parent directory.

Answer (score 0):

right click on the folder (not right click on nothing in the folder, the icon of the folder you want to clone INTO from the parent directory) and select `clone` from the menu.

FYI:

`clone = create a copy of a repository.`

`checkout = change the current state of an existing repo to a saved state.`

so if you have a repo w/ 3 commits (A,B,C) when you clone the repo you will be at the most current state (C). if you want to see the previous state of the repo you would `git checkout B`. if you want to see the repo's initial state you would `git checkout A`

hope that helps.

Comment: I have tried it, as you suggested but it still does not work. Still unable to get "Clone" or "Create Git Repository" by right click appear. Can this rely on settings? Should I have to change anything in the TortoiseGit settings?